# Horizonatal Scrolling in FlowDocumentScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, flowdocumentscrollviewer

I have a flow document with images (created from drawings). I have provided a button for the user to enlarge the images (zoom) independently without zooming the text.

Is there anyway, I can force the FlowDocumentScrollViewer to display a horizontal scrollbar for scrolling when the images are enlarged? Currently, the enlarged images are simply clipped off.

Best regards,
Paul.

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer, setting the PageWidth of the document does the trick.